# Batch remove obsolete branches in Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have Bitbucket repository that has more than 300 branches, most of them are useless and obsolete. I want to remove all the all branches that are older than one month (or, simpler, keep only last 100 branches). In addition, I need to save all branches whose name contains 'release' or some other stop-words. Is there any way to do that in Bitbucket UI or somehow else?
I've tried to do it manually one by one and this is very slow and tedious way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen some other solutions but decided to try using selenium.  If you're interesting what happened in the end, you can find it here:

https://github.com/globad/remove-old-branches

All you need is to clone the repository, download the proper version of Chrome-webdriver, input few constants like URL to your repository and run the script.